# Is there a Mongoose event for data access?

Tags: mongoose

I'm doing some tests in my application to see if memory-cache is actually working. However, since memory-cache apparently doesn't expose a "on hit" event, I can't tell if is actually taking data from the cache or not. So I tried to see if there is a mongoose event that is fired when the app actually get some data from the Database, but again it seems there is not. I was wondering if there such event? And if so which one it is? I tried using this snippet of code.

```
mongoose.on("open", () => {
  console.log("Open DB conn");
});
```

But is fired off only on app start when I initially connect to the database.

Comment: What is `mongoose` in your use case? Is it `mongoose.connection`? Also, the `open` event only fires once the connection is established, i.e. when the connection is open. So when you say it is only fired off when the you initially connect to the databases that is to be expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no event for evaluating or auditing memory cache in mongoose. The events you are referring to are in regards to the connection itself. Items such as `connecting`, `connected`, `open`, and `close` are examples of such events. You can see a full list of connection events in the [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#connection-events).

Depending on whether or not you have specified a separate storage engine, the default for mongodb is [WiredTiger](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/wiredtiger/).

To determine if you are accessing cached memory from WiredTiger, you can refer to the selected answer for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49221499/how-to-detect-if-my-query-result-is-retrieved-from-wiredtiger-cache) stack post, which states:

> Any query will result in WiredTiger loading the document from disk into its part of memory (the so-called "cache") in an uncompressed form. Therefore **all** query replies are served from the "cache".

As for a method or function to audit whether or not it is used cached memory I can not immediately think of any. One way you could figure it out is to determine how long it takes the queries when you have caching enabled versus when you have it disabled/cleared. One way you can remove cached queries is by using `db.collection.getPlanCache().clear()`.

If the query time is quicker when caching is enabled, then you know the cache is working.

Comment: I get it, yes when caching is enabled response times are indeed lowers, but I want to check this just to be 100% sure that everything is working correctly, since I'm still pretty new to Node and Mongoose :)

Comment: Also, do I need something particular to use WiredTiger with the latest version of Mongoose? Or it has nothing to do with Mongoose in general? (sorry if it sounds like a dumb question but this is the first time i heard about it)

Comment: Not a dumb question at all. I am not totally sure. Today, the default storage engine for MongoDB is WiredTiger. In previous versions (before 3.2), it was MMAPv1. This [blog post](https://www.percona.com/blog/2017/03/07/how-to-change-mongodb-storage-engines-without-downtime/) goes over how to change your storage engine though I have never done this myself. Since WiredTiger is the default for MongoDBB I assume it is the default for mongoose.

Comment: Yes, I looked deeper into documentation and it looks like is a MongoDB setting. However, there are some examples using the MongoDB driver for Node.js where they explicitly set the storage-engine option, so I'm not sure if is just not implemented yet in mongoose or what. By the way, since I'm caching the GraphQL response, I can live with this doubt for now 